# Debugging and the actual test result differs when mocking a object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, junit5, mockk

I have written a testcase in which I mock a object using mockk. The problem is that when I run the testcase and debug using Intellij I do get the mocked response inside the debug window but when I let the testcase finish I get an error of my database client (so it ran the actual method instead).

The following is my simplified service code:

```
class SendMessageService (
    private val authHelper: AuthHelper
) {
    companion object {
        val targetsDb = TargetsDynamodbService()
    }

    fun handlePushIdRequest(sendMessageRequest: SendMessageRequest): Observable<List<Target>> {
        if (!validAuthorization(sendMessageRequest.serviceKey)) {
            throw ClientErrorException("Invalid Authorization", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
        }

        return targetsDb.getAllTargetsAsObservable(sendMessageRequest.pushId)
    }

    private fun validAuthorization(serviceKey: ServiceKey): Boolean {
        val authorization = authHelper.getTargetId("service key")

        return authorization == Configuration.SendMessageAuthorization.authorization(serviceKey)
    }
}
```

With this as simplified testcase:

```
class SendMessageServiceTest : AbstractServiceTest() {
    private val authHelper = AuthHelper(listOf("abc"))

    private val targetsDynamodbService: TargetsDynamodbService = mockk()
    private lateinit var service: SendMessageService

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        mockkObject(SendMessageService.Companion)
        every { SendMessageService.Companion.targetsDb } returns targetsDynamodbService
        ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("sendmessage.authorization.test", "abc")
    }

    @Test
    fun `successfully send pushId request message`() {
        every { targetsDynamodbService.getAllTargetsAsObservable(any()) } answers {
            Observable.just(listOf(Target().apply { pushId = arg<String>(0) }))
        }
        service = SendMessageService(authHelper)

        val response = service.handlePushIdRequests(createMessageRequest()).blockingFirst()
        assertTrue(response.isNotEmpty())
    }


    private fun createMessageRequest() =
        SendMessageRequest(
            pushId = "pushId",
            serviceKey = ServiceKey.TEST,
            title = TextLocalization("en", "nl"),
            body = TextLocalization("en", "nl"),
            silent = false,
            collapseKey = null,
            data = null,
            androidOptions = null,
            iosOptions = null
        )
}
```

What am I missing that a debug and the actual testcase result can differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`every { ... }` mocks a function, not a field. In your particular case Kotlin compiler doesn't generate getter and setter for a field because it's not required.
So to solve your problem you have to force compiler to generate getter (which is a function) for the desired property, e.g. using `by lazy`:

**Trick #1**

```kotlin
companion object {
    val targetsDb by lazy { TargetsDynamodbService() }
}
```

... or to declare getter explicitly:

**Trick #2**

```kotlin
companion object {
    private val _targetsDb = TargetsDynamodbService() // backing field

    val targetsDb: TargetsDynamodbService
        get() = _targetsDb     // get() is an explicit getter for _targetsDb 
}
```

P.S. However, I'd recommend you to review the design of your class, and consider about injecting `targetsDb` through constructor rather than instantiating it inside Companion object.